# How can i export Thumbprint from a certificate file in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a problem that I want to program a simple application which export some data like thumbprint(as like as click on *.cer file in windows, and then you can see serial number of certificate file or  it's thumbprint, ....). I want to do this job in c++\mfc, and I will be thankful if someone gently give me advise like is there any class or library to handle and retrieve data from *.cer file?

Comment: StackOverflow is not designed for this kind of evasive questions. Try to do something, and come with specific questions.

Comment: @Cadchon actually I want to know about a specific good library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a Windows only solution, I would use Win32 API. Have a look at [CryptQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CryptMsgGetParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380227%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There is an example of how to get information from a certificate in the [windows documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323809):

```
WCHAR szFileName[] = L"certificate.cer"; 
DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
DWORD dwSignerInfo;
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL;

fResult = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
                           szFileName,
                           CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
                           CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
                           0,
                           &dwEncoding,
                           &dwContentType,
                           &dwFormatType,
                           &hStore,
                           &hMsg,
                           NULL);


// Get signer information size.
fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
                           CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
                           0, 
                           NULL, 
                           &dwSignerInfo);

// Allocate memory for signer information.
pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSignerInfo);

// Get Signer Information.
fResult = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
                           CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
                           0, 
                           (PVOID)pSignerInfo, 
                           &dwSignerInfo);

// use pSignerInfo->SerialNumber
```

Of course you should handle errors, the example is more detailed in the link above but it's a start. You'll have to be more specific as to what you are after if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: Actually I need something like this.Thank you man